# Kendo UI and ASP.NET MVC : Server side filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, pagination, telerik

I have a Kendo grid for which I want server-side filtering, paging and sorting.

The grid is implemented with plain JavaScript using the jQuery version of Kendo, so I don't have access to the Kendo C# HTML Helpers. The Data Source looks something like this:

```
new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
     url: '/MyEndpoint',
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'get'
    },
  },
  schema: {
   data: 'data',
   total: 'total'
  },
  serverPaging: true,
  serverFiltering: true,
  serverSorting: true
 });
```

It sends requests with this structure:

```
/Endpoint/?take=20&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=20&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=Name&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=eq&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=test&filter%5Blogic%5D=and
```

My controller looks as described in the Kendo docs:

```
public IHttpActionResult MyControler([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest req)
{
   return Json(SomeQuery.ToDataSourceResult(req));
}
```

The problem is that the controller can't seem to match the url parameters to the controller. When the controller action is called, req is always null. Is it even possible to do this with the jQuery version of Kendo? I can't find any example in the docs that doesn't use the C# HTML helpers to achieve server side grid filtering/paging/sorting.